# Difference between []*Users and *[]Users in Golang?

Tags: pointers, go, struct

While I had to point some data to a struct, I just got confused on the difference between `[]*Users` and `*[]Users` in Golang struct

I have following struct

```
type Users struct {
    ID int
    Name string
}
```

Comment: Reading the type from left to right: the first is a slice of pointers to User structs, the second is a pointer to a slice of User structs.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The difference is quite large:

`*[]Users` would be a pointer to a slice of `Users`. Ex:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Users struct {
    ID int
    Name string
}

var (
    userList []Users
)

func main(){
    //Make the slice of Users
    userList = []Users{Users{ID: 43215, Name: "Billy"}}

    //Then pass the slice as a reference to some function
    myFunc(&userList);

    fmt.Println(userList) // Outputs: [{1337 Bobby}]
}


//Now the function gets a pointer *[]Users that when changed, will affect the global variable "userList"
func myFunc(input *[]Users){
    *input = []Users{Users{ID: 1337, Name: "Bobby"}}
}
```

On the contrary, `[]*Users` would be a slice of pointers to `Users`. Ex:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Users struct {
    ID int
    Name string
}

var (
    user1 Users
    user2 Users
)

func main(){
    //Make a couple Users:
    user1 = Users{ID: 43215, Name: "Billy"}
    user2 = Users{ID: 84632, Name: "Bobby"}

    //Then make a list of pointers to those Users:
    var userList []*Users = []*Users{&user1, &user2}

    //Now you can change an individual Users in that list.
    //This changes the variable user2:
    *userList[1] = Users{ID:1337, Name: "Larry"}

    fmt.Println(user1) // Outputs: {43215 Billy}
    fmt.Println(user2) // Outputs: {1337 Larry}
}
```

Both use pointers, but in completely different ways. Mess around with both of these snippets for yourself at [Golang Playground](https://play.golang.org/) and read through [this](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/1) to get a better understanding.

Comment: please how can we append to `userList` in the second example